# Prevent IvyDE from resolving specific build time dependencies

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy, build-dependencies, ivyde

Its maybe that I'm trying to misuse Ivy, but if I am then I definitely don't understand 'configurations'

I have a dependency I want to access only when running my build script under Jenkins.  In my eclipse workspace I have no need for the dependency.  Is it possible to achieve this?

For example if I wanted to pull ant-contrib in at build time I have tried setting up my configuration file as follows:

```
<configurations defaultconf="compile">
    <conf name="compile" visibility="public" />
    <conf name="build" visibility="public" extends="compile" />
</configurations>

<dependencies>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.1" conf="compile->default" />
    <dependency org="ant-contrib" name="ant-contrib" rev="1.0b3" conf="build->*" />
</dependencies>
```

With this example I always end up with ant contrib and ant on my build path in eclipse which isn't what I wanted.  The resolve ant task allows me to resolve a specific configuration so I assumed that IvyDE would only resolve the default one.  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the ivy file using IvyDE it is possible to select the configurations that should be resolved.  This way only compile can be selected and only junit would be resolved.

It seems that to change this you need to remove and re-add the ivy dependency, I can't find any settings to change the configurations without doing that.